# How do I get the path of a Requirement and TestSetFolder in HP ALM with workflows?

Tags: workflow, alm

I'm new to HP ALM and it's workflows and already kept searching but wasn't able to find a working solution.

How am I able to get the full path of a Requirement and a TestSetFolder? 
I managed to find a solution for TestFolders but I'm not able to transfer the solution :

```
    dim TreeManager
    dim SubjectNode
    dim FolderID
    dim tdc 

    FolderID = Req_Fields.Field("AL_ITEM_ID").Value        
    set tdc = TDConnection        
    set TreeManager = tdc.TreeManager
    set SubjectNode = TreeManager.NodeById(FolderID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full path of a Requirement, please see the example below.

```
reqID = Req_Fields.Field("RQ_REQ_ID").Value
Set reqFactory = TDConnection.ReqFactory
Set reqFilter = reqFactory.Filter
reqFilter.Filter("RQ_REQ_ID") = reqID       
Set reqList = reqFactory.NewList(reqFilter.Text)
For Each tItem in reqList
    MsgBox tItem.Path
Next
```

To get the full path of a TestSetFolder, please see the example below.

```
Set testSetTreeManager = TDConnection.TestSetTreeManager
Set testSetFolder = testSetTreeManager.NodebyID(TestSetFolder_Fields("CF_ITEM_ID").value)
MsgBox testSetFolder.Path
```

Hope this can help you.